# Getting Errno::ENOENT during Dir.foreach block when I know file exists?

Tags: ruby, file, foreach, directory

I currently have the path set to:

```
$: << "C:/Users/fireforkingjesus/ruby/note/"
```

I have these things in this folder: `ruby/note/notes/`

```
!IMPORTANT - folder
just.txt
inventory.txt
weapons.txt
```

And if I put this code it works fine:

```
Dir.foreach("notes/"){|file| puts file}
```

Outputs:

```
.  
..  
!IMPORTANT   
just.txt  
inventory.txt   
weapons.txt
```

But THESE codes do not work:

```
Dir.foreach("notes/"){|file| puts file if File.exist?(file)}
```

This above^^ puts

```
.    
..
```

and

```
Dir.foreach("notes/"){|file| puts File.exist?(file)}
```

Returns `true` 2 times and `false` 4 times

```
Dir.foreach("notes/"){ |file|  puts File.ftype(file)}
```

This above^^ returns: "No such file or directory -!IMPORTANT" (Errno::ENOENT)

I've even done this:

```
f = "inventory.txt"    
puts "yes before foreach" if File.exist?("notes/inventory.txt")     
Dir.foreach("notes/"){ |file|     
  puts "yes in foreach" if File.exist?("inventory.txt")     
  puts File.ftype(f)     
}
```

I get:

```
yes before foreach    
No such file or directory -inventory.txt (Errno::ENOENT)`
```

I have Ruby 2.0, Windows 8. I thought maybe permissions? or something idk
and I also tried it on my dad's Win vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look a little closer at your output:

```
Dir.foreach("notes/"){|file| puts file}
# ----------^^^^^^^^
```

produces:

```
.
..
!IMPORTANT
just.txt
inventory.txt
weapons.txt
```

[`Dir.foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) is handing the basenames to the block so you'll have to put the path back on if `Dir` isn't looking at the current directory:

```
Dir.foreach("notes/") { |file| puts File.ftype("#{notes}/file") }
```

Everything works fine with `.` and `..` of course, those exist in every directory.

Comment: You are very right. In fact i JUST figured that out and came on to answer my own question. Thanks for your help.