# why does my dir.foreach not recogize my path in ruby

Tags: ruby

here is my code below

```
folder_results = Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd) {|x| File.extname(x) }
```

ive also tryed:

```
folder_results = Dir.foreach("nice/") {|x| File.extname(x) }
```

Here is my Ruby cmd errors, Ive attempt this many times , in many different ways

you can see the ruby path used in the Ruby cmd

[image: Ruby cmd errors]

Edit:

This is what the file dir looks like of nice :

[image: List of folders]

Comment: there is more code but I believe I must be doing something wrong here

Comment: Please show all your code.  And what are you trying to accomplish.  Dir.foreach returns nil as it just executed the block on each item that gets passed to it

Comment: I still get the same error with just that one line of code

Comment: please give the full method;

Comment: this is full method, I wrote this in as a file on its own same error

Comment: Im thinking of reinstalling ruby

Comment: no Ruby is working fine

Comment: you just have something wrong here "Dir.pwd"

Comment: folder_results = Dir.foreach("nice/") {|x| File.extname(x) }

Comment: yes ive try others as well

Comment: What results are you expecting. try doing a `puts Dir.pwd` before the foreach to verify you are in the correct directory.  take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991442/getting-errnoenoent-during-dir-foreach-block-when-i-know-file-exists  it might help

Comment: BTW according to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) `folder_results = Dir.foreach("nice/") {|x| File.extname(x) }` will result in `folder_results` being `nil`. I think you meant to add `map` between `foreach(...)` and the block itself

Answer (score 1):

You should save the `File.extname` result to an array instead of directly assigning result from `Dir.foreach` which always returns nil.

```
folder_results = []
Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd) { |x| folder_results << File.extname(x) }
```

Now you can get the file name extensions from `folder_results` array.

Else, you can use `map`. Thanks [engineersmnky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978251/engineersmnky) for pointing out this.

```
folder_results = Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd).map { |x| File.extname(x) } –
```

Comment: `map` is more idiomatic e.g. `folder_results = Dir.foreach(Dir.pwd).map { |x|  File.extname(x) }`

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. I just explained the behaviour of  actual code. I will update answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error message comes from `Dir.foreach` and says that the supplied argument is not a directory.

In the case where you simply put 'nice' as argument, I would conclude that this directory does not exist, but since the error message also appears for `Dir.pwd` as argument, it means that Ruby's idea of what the working directory is, must be messed up. Actually, the error message says that the result of `Dir.pwd` would be the string `pwd`, which is nonsense: `Dir.pwd` always returns an absolute path. To verify that this is really the case, I would do a `puts(Dir.pwd)` before the offending line, but I guess that this will also show `pwd`.

This means that you will have to find out, at which point in your program the working directory gets messed up. It must be OK at the program start (but please check!), and narrow down the search until you find the culprit.

BTW, aside from this problem, your program is logically flawed. You calculate all the file extensions, but then throw the result away, and folder_results will always be `nil`.